# Filtering layers in web map legend based on viewing extent using ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online, hosted-feature-layer

I am creating a web map for my organization which has several natural preserve sites in a given state. This is intended as a simple introduction for the public where they can view basic details of all the reserves from one public map i.e. boundary, walking trails, kayak trails as some are coastal.

I'm using visibility ranges such that at the statewide level users only see locations points for our sites and offices, and when they zoom into a specific preserve, trail layers and other specifics appear. Problem is that the legend will show all the layers within the visibility range, even if they're not in the map extent. Ex. I zoom to Site A, there's Site A layer 1, Site A layer 2, but also layers for Sites B, C, and so on. Of course for trails I could merge them into one statewide trail file, but we have various site-specific projects or features that aren't uniform for all sites. Ex. Site C has prohibited federal property but most others don't.

**Is there a way to filter content on a web map legend based on what's viewable in the user's extent?**

Preferably with a web map since we embed those in our website and want it to be as simple as possible for public viewing.

I have tried using a feature layer view definition, but that defines what features are viewable from that feature layer, not what extent the feature layer can be viewed in by a user.

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to produce this behaviour with an "out of the box" product. It may be possible if you were to custom build an app (hosted on your own server). But this of course requires a server and knowledge in scripting :) https://developers.arcgis.com/web-appbuilder/

Comment: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/sandbox/sandbox.html?sample=widget_legend, kindly check this.